# AccountManager does not add custom account in Android N preview

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-syncadapter, android-account, android-authenticator

I have implemented a sync adapter in my app which requires an account to be added in the device account settings. I followed the same approach given in the Android docs. It works fine till Marshmallow and I can see my account listed in the device accounts. But in Android N preview, account does not add to the device accounts. AccountManager's addAccountExplicitly() method always returns false. Has anyone faced this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is the same issue, but there's an issue with AccountManager on the current version of the Android N image. Basically, if you:

1. Add an account to AccountManager
2. Uninstall the app
3. Reinstall the app
4. Try to add account again

This will fail and you'll see the following in the log:

`W/AccountManagerService( 1503): insertAccountIntoDatabase: Account {name=foo@bar.com, type=com.foo.bar}, skipping since the account already exists`

This is a known issue and it's been reported to Google:
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210992
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=210951

Answer (score 1):

I have totally the same issue. 
I could fix it by manually going to the application settings and enabling **Сontacts** permission. I don't know how, but after that I was able to use `addAccountExplicitly()` method without issues. I even disabled that permission again and cleared app data but it still was working properly...

After app was reinstalled - problem appeared again.

Answer (score 0):

Has this been fixed now in the latest Android N release.